# Module not found: Can't resolve 'react/jsx-runtime' in '/client/node_modules/@mui/icons-material' in Docker implementation

Tags: reactjs, docker, material-ui

" Whenever I build and start to run my dockerized react application, it keeps on giving the error mentioned in the title. Although I separately give the package installation command in my Dockerfile, still get the same error. I also installed package jsx-runtime but no result. Anybody who can guide me, please."

```
FROM node:16-alpine
# set the working directory
WORKDIR /client

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /client/node_modules/.bin:$PATH


# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./

RUN npm install --force
RUN npm install -g nodemon
RUN npm install --save ra-data-json-server --force
RUN npm install @material-ui/core --force
RUN npm install @material/theme --force
Run npm install jsx-runtime --force

COPY . ./

EXPOSE 3000

CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

Comment: Post your Dockerfile

Comment: How are you starting your application?  Are you bind-mounting a host directory over `/client`, causing everything that's in this Dockerfile to be ignored?  Are you bind-mounting a volume over `node_modules`, so that changes to your `package.json` get lost in favor of the older volume content?

Comment: @DavidMaze  If i didn't understand u wrong, than am simply running my docker file in client folder directory , what you suggest me to change, as you told that something ignored, how and where, please let me know and am not using any mount word anywhere in my script even or command. simple docker run -p 3000:3000 file name

Comment: Do you have a `.dockerignore` file?  (It should usually include `node_modules`, so that the final `COPY ./ ./` line doesn't overwrite what was previously `npm install`ed.)  The handful of extra `npm install individual-package --force` seems suspicious to me too, does it work any better if you delete all of these extra lines and just install the packages and versions from the `package{,-lock}.json`?

Answer (score 0):

I deleted package.json and node modules before building my docker file, and then added `npm install` inside Dockerfile. It has worked for me.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).